# Double arrow in prolog

Tags: prolog

In sequent calculus there is a double arrow that is read as the conjunction to the left of the arrow implies the disjunction to the right of the arrow. Is there a symbol for this in Prolog? The symbol can be written as => or |-.

Comment: *...that is read as the conjunction to the left of the arrow implies the disjunction to the left of the arrow.* I'm having trouble understanding that sentence.

Comment: I was looking up some of the definitions for *sequent calculus*. I suppose that, in Prolog, the expression `head :- q1, q2, ..., qn.` is, in some limited sense, like `q1, q2, ..., qn |- head`. In sequent calculus, the ordering of `qi` shouldn't matter, so in Prolog, that corresponds to a pure predicate implementation.

Comment: Let's say there is a formula (A, B "double arrow" C, D). That would be translated to (A and B) -> (C or D).

Comment: Assuming by `->` you mean implication, then in Prolog, you'd have `C :- A, B.` and `D :- A, B.`. That says that `C` succeeds if `A` and `B` succeed, or `D` succeeds if `A` and `B` succeed.

Comment: You can use `'|-'` as operator. Not the nicest choice, though

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the vertical bar ('|') is not classified as graphic in ISO Prolog. It is rather classified as solo like the comma (','). This choice for the vertical bar was possibly done because it is used together with the comma as a a separator in tailed lists, like for example [X,Y|Z].

As a result the vertical bar doesn't combine and form a token with other graphic characters. So you can for example write the graphic characters minus ('-') and greater than ('>') together to form -> which is read as one token. This doesn't work for the vertical bar.

But a couple of Prolog systems meanwhile support [unicode](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/#MOCSH). So one way out would be to directly use the unicode [turnstile](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/22a2/index.htm) ⊢ (U+22A2). Here is what works so far in two Prolog systems:

SWI-Prolog:

```
?- op(1100,xfx,⊢).
true.

?- X = (F ⊢ G).
X =  (F⊢G).
```

Jekejeke Prolog:

```
?- op(1100,xfx,⊢).
Yes

?- X = (F ⊢ G).
X = (F⊢G)
```